# How can I set up multiple libraries in Rhythmbox?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I'd like to separate my music into multiple libraries to better organize it, but anything I can find seems to be outdated. Does it still require hacky solutions to do this or is it easier now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to edit the configuration key directly, either using the `gsettings` command line tool, or using `dconf-editor` as a GUI. The key is `locations` under `org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to these configuration options, but I guess I should clarify: I want to divide my entire library into multiple ones (each with its own playlists, etc.) and not just combine music from various locations. Is this possible in Rhythmbox?

Comment: Playlists are basically separate from the library itself. However, when you define multiple library locations in that configuration option, an expander triangle will appear next to the "Music" entry in the tree, and each library will be listed separately under it. You can also match on the path when creating an automatic playlist.

Comment: I never even noticed that before. I guess I'll start organizing by folders. Thanks!