# music player with audiobook support

Tags: music-player, audiobooks, audio-player

Hello I'm looking for a nice audio player with audio-book and network support. I know banshee has that but i rather use something that isn't coded in mono. Another no no is KDE programs, Qt is fine but not a program that was especially developed for KDE like Amarok.

I've looked at a couple like clementine, guayadeque, audacious and so on, but no one besides banshee seams to have audio-book support.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Rhythmbox doesn't have audiobook support directly, but it does support multiple, distinct libraries, one of which could be just for your audiobooks. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168494/how-can-i-set-up-multiple-libraries-in-rhythmbox) for details. This won't do anything clever, like support chapters etc, but it may be enough.